# embed javascript/library inside apple ibooks author

Tags: javascript, webkit, ibooks

What kind of html5 support is provided inside Apple ibooks? Is it possible, or limitations to include javascript libraries such as d3.js, three.js (WebGL support), reactjs, angularjs?

In other words, is the webkit inside ibooks a full featured browser?